# Can an envelope created from a template be used in embedded signing?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to implement the following steps:

1. Find a pre-created template by templateId.
2. Use the template to create an envelope.
3. Create a link for the envelope so that the signer can click in and sign it (same as embedded signing).

I have tried the APIs and it seemed that an envelope created from a template can only be sent by email instead of embedded signing. I would like to know how to achieve the above goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you use the template to create an envelope and you are specifying recipient info, you would need to specify the clientUserId parameter to mark the recipient as an embedded recipient.

So basically your request would look something like this,

```
"emailSubject": "This request is sent from a Template",
"templateId": "55A80182-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-FD1E1C0F9D74",
"templateRoles": [{
    "roleName": "Signer1",
     "name": "Hank Scorpio",
     "email": "hscorpio@example.com",
     "clientUserId": "Your clientUserId"
}],
"status": "sent"
```